# How to get titles on each box?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I tried to color all of the divs differently for easier viewing. I would like to add a title to each, preferable in the bottom left hand corner of each box. If that is possible, that would be great. Also, these divs are responsive to mobile view so being able to get the text to work around that would be useful too. Thanks in advance.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper > div {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  padding: 3em;
  color: white;
    
}.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.one {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  background-image: url('https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/images/hp2000/hdspr/hdslide11.gif');
  background-position: 610px 500px;
}
.two { 
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 /3;
  background-image: url('http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-indigo-web-solid-color-background.jpg');
}
.three {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2 /3;
  background-image: url('http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/GreenBackground.png');
}
.four {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  background-image: url('http://www.ledr.com/colours/grey.jpg');
}
.five {
  grid-column: 1 /3;
  grid-row: 3;
  background-image: url('https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/images/hp2000/hdspr/hdslide11.gif');
}
.six {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 4 ;
  background-image: url('http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-indigo-web-solid-color-background.jpg');
}
.seven {
  grid-column: 1;
  background-image: url('http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/GreenBackground.png');
}

.eight {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 8 / 5;
  background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3qlRNWBWr5o/maxresdefault.jpg');
}

.nine {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 7/5;
  background-image: url('https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/images/hp2000/hdspr/hdslide11.gif');
}

.ten {
  grid-column: 3;
  background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3qlRNWBWr5o/maxresdefault.jpg');
}
.eleven {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 7/6;
  background-image: url('http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-indigo-web-solid-color-background.jpg');
}
.twelve {
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 7;
  background-image: url('http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/GreenBackground.png');
}
.thirteen {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 8 ;
  background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3qlRNWBWr5o/maxresdefault.jpg');
}
/*HOVER*/
.one:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}
.two:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}
.three:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}
.four:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}
.five:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}
.six:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}
.eight:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}
.nine:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}
.ten:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}
.eleven:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}
.twelve:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}
.thirteen:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .wrapper {
   display: block;
 }
 .margin-bot {
   margin-bottom: 2px;
 }

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    
    <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="one margin-bot"></div>
    
    <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="two margin-bot"></div>
    
    <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="three margin-bot"></div>
    
    <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="three margin-bot"></div>
    
    <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="four margin-bot"></div>
    
    <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="five margin-bot"></div>
    
    <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="six margin-bot"></div>
    
    <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="eight margin-bot"></div>
    
    <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="nine margin-bot"></div>
    
    <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="ten margin-bot"></div>
    
    <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="eleven margin-bot"></div>
    
    <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="twelve margin-bot"></div>
    
    <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="thirteen margin-bot"></div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `<span>` element inside each div and add the following CSS. I have implemented for first div with class `one`.

Changes made:

1. Added `position:relative` to div with class `one`.
2. For span under `div`, added the following:

`.one span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}`

```css
.wrapper {
 max-width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper>div {
 background-color: lightcoral;
 padding: 3em;
 color: white;
}

.wrapper {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
 grid-gap: 15px;
 grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.one {
 grid-column: 1;
 grid-row: 1;
 background-image: url('https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/images/hp2000/hdspr/hdslide11.gif');
 background-position: 610px 500px;
 position: relative;
}

.one span {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.two {
 grid-column: 2;
 grid-row: 1 /3;
 background-image: url('http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-indigo-web-solid-color-background.jpg');
}

.three {
 grid-column: 1;
 grid-row: 2 /3;
 background-image: url('http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/GreenBackground.png');
}

.four {
 grid-column: 3;
 grid-row: 1 / 4;
 background-image: url('http://www.ledr.com/colours/grey.jpg');
}

.five {
 grid-column: 1 /3;
 grid-row: 3;
 background-image: url('https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/images/hp2000/hdspr/hdslide11.gif');
}

.six {
 grid-column: 1 / 4;
 grid-row: 4;
 background-image: url('http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-indigo-web-solid-color-background.jpg');
}

.seven {
 grid-column: 1;
 background-image: url('http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/GreenBackground.png');
}

.eight {
 grid-column: 1;
 grid-row: 8 / 5;
 background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3qlRNWBWr5o/maxresdefault.jpg');
}

.nine {
 grid-column: 2;
 grid-row: 7/5;
 background-image: url('https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/images/hp2000/hdspr/hdslide11.gif');
}

.ten {
 grid-column: 3;
 background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3qlRNWBWr5o/maxresdefault.jpg');
}

.eleven {
 grid-column: 3;
 grid-row: 7/6;
 background-image: url('http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-indigo-web-solid-color-background.jpg');
}

.twelve {
 grid-column: 2/4;
 grid-row: 7;
 background-image: url('http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/GreenBackground.png');
}

.thirteen {
 grid-column: 1/4;
 grid-row: 8;
 background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3qlRNWBWr5o/maxresdefault.jpg');
}
/*HOVER*/

.one:hover {
 opacity: .6;
}

.two:hover {
 opacity: .6;
}

.three:hover {
 opacity: .6;
}

.four:hover {
 opacity: .6;
}

.five:hover {
 opacity: .6;
}

.six:hover {
 opacity: .6;
}

.eight:hover {
 opacity: .6;
}

.nine:hover {
 opacity: .6;
}

.ten:hover {
 opacity: .6;
}

.eleven:hover {
 opacity: .6;
}

.twelve:hover {
 opacity: .6;
}

.thirteen:hover {
 opacity: .6;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .wrapper {
  display: block;
 }
 .margin-bot {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

 <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="one margin-bot">
  <span>One</span>
 </div>

 <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="two margin-bot"></div>

 <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="three margin-bot"></div>

 <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="three margin-bot"></div>

 <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="four margin-bot"></div>

 <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="five margin-bot"></div>

 <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="six margin-bot"></div>

 <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="eight margin-bot"></div>

 <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="nine margin-bot"></div>

 <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="ten margin-bot"></div>

 <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="eleven margin-bot"></div>

 <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="twelve margin-bot"></div>

 <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="thirteen margin-bot"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a flexbox would be a natural choice since you are using `CSS3 Grid` here. Make you *grid items* a `flexbox` and align the text on each *grid item* to the bottom left (maybe adjust your `padding` too?) using:

```
display: flex;
align-items: flex-end; /* align to the bottom */
justify-content: flex-start; /* align to the left */
```

See demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  padding: 3em;
  color: white;
  
  /* ADDED THESE*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.one {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  background-image: url('https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/images/hp2000/hdspr/hdslide11.gif');
  background-position: 610px 500px;
}

.two {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 /3;
  background-image: url('http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-indigo-web-solid-color-background.jpg');
}

.three {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2 /3;
  background-image: url('http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/GreenBackground.png');
}

.four {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  background-image: url('http://www.ledr.com/colours/grey.jpg');
}

.five {
  grid-column: 1 /3;
  grid-row: 3;
  background-image: url('https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/images/hp2000/hdspr/hdslide11.gif');
}

.six {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 4;
  background-image: url('http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-indigo-web-solid-color-background.jpg');
}

.seven {
  grid-column: 1;
  background-image: url('http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/GreenBackground.png');
}

.eight {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 8 / 5;
  background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3qlRNWBWr5o/maxresdefault.jpg');
}

.nine {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 7/5;
  background-image: url('https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/images/hp2000/hdspr/hdslide11.gif');
}

.ten {
  grid-column: 3;
  background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3qlRNWBWr5o/maxresdefault.jpg');
}

.eleven {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 7/6;
  background-image: url('http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-indigo-web-solid-color-background.jpg');
}

.twelve {
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 7;
  background-image: url('http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/GreenBackground.png');
}

.thirteen {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 8;
  background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3qlRNWBWr5o/maxresdefault.jpg');
}


/*HOVER*/

.one:hover {
  opacity: .6;
}

.two:hover {
  opacity: .6;
}

.three:hover {
  opacity: .6;
}

.four:hover {
  opacity: .6;
}

.five:hover {
  opacity: .6;
}

.six:hover {
  opacity: .6;
}

.eight:hover {
  opacity: .6;
}

.nine:hover {
  opacity: .6;
}

.ten:hover {
  opacity: .6;
}

.eleven:hover {
  opacity: .6;
}

.twelve:hover {
  opacity: .6;
}

.thirteen:hover {
  opacity: .6;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: block;
  }
  .margin-bot {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="one margin-bot">one</div>

  <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="two margin-bot">two</div>

  <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="three margin-bot">three</div>

  <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="three margin-bot">four</div>

  <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="four margin-bot">five</div>

  <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="five margin-bot">six</div>

  <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="six margin-bot">seven</div>

  <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="eight margin-bot">eight</div>

  <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="nine margin-bot">nine</div>

  <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="ten margin-bot">ten</div>

  <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="eleven margin-bot">eleven</div>

  <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="twelve margin-bot">twelve</div>

  <div onclick="location.href='landing.html';" style="cursor: pointer;" class="thirteen margin-bot">thirteen</div>
</div>
```